# Failure to Login

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop

I have Copied **Hadoop-Eclipse plugin** to plugin folder of Eclipse and also made SSH psw less but when i try to create new DFS location it gets created but it throws error like An internal error occurred during: "*Map/Reduce location status updater".org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException* and ubable to connect to DFS directory, it says ***failure to login***, I am new to Hadoop, Please help me to get rid of this.
I keep the same port no in Map/Reducer and Master DFS as same as I keep in Conf files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error with Hadoop-0.20.203. I think there are some issues in having this version work with eclipse. Try reading about them and find if your issue is related.